# How we can Identify values coming from which tables and columns from Database using XML file

Tags: sql, xml

we have one front end application where we create products and information of those we get in xml format. Now, I wanted to use that xml file to check from which tables and columns values are getting generated. I wanted that in sql (when we use xml file in sql it should help me to identify tables and columns from where data is collected while working on front end)

Comment: Your question is very broad. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I succeed calling xml file in sql but not able to filter xml data in their respective DB tables.

Comment: Any suggestion guys?

Comment: You question is difficult to understand without data samples and what expected result you are looking for. Edit your question, and add as much information, as you can, what have you tried and what is you exact issue